# how can I install mecab library error on colab environment

Tags: google-colaboratory, mecab

I can't install mecab library on google colab environment. [code image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k1Y1r.png)

I tried this code, but error messeage happend. I thought that I wrote right install code, but error message..

[error result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wVV3p.png)

plz help me, how can I fix this error?

[code 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/67IGU.png)
I tried this code too.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you also need a Python wrapper for `mecab`.

1. Run the below code block in a Google Colab cell to install all the needed dependencies.

```
%%bash
sudo apt-get install g++ openjdk-8-jdk python3-dev python3-pip curl
bash <(curl -s https://raw.githubusercontent.com/konlpy/konlpy/master/scripts/mecab.sh)
pip install konlpy
pip install mecab-python3
```

2. Import Mecab and run a function to check the code is working

```
from konlpy.tag import Mecab

mecab = Mecab()

text = '나는 파이썬으로 코딩하는 것을 좋아합니다'
result = mecab.pos(text)
print(result)

#result
[('나', 'NP'), ('는', 'JX'), ('파이썬', 'NNP'), ('으로', 'JKB'), ('코딩', 'NNG'), ('하', 'XSV'), ('는', 'ETM'), ('것', 'NNB'), ('을', 'JKO'), ('좋아합니다', 'VV+EC')]
```